# Is there a difference in pronunciation between 'two' and 'chew'?

Tags: differences, pronunciation

As a child my English teacher stressed continuously that we need to pronounce correctly the word "two" and "chew", pointing out that English-speaking people would hear a notable difference in their pronunciations.

Comment: Is it just those two words or is it the "t" and "ch" sounds? They're definitely distinct in English, but you may have grown up with a language that doesn't distinguish between them, so hearing the difference might be difficult ([This book](https://www.amazon.com/Scientist-Crib-Early-Learning-Tells/dp/0688177883) explains some science behind that).

Comment: Yes, there is typically a difference.  Probably the best way to understand it is to carefully watch a native English speaker making the two sounds.  For "two" the lips form a uniform oval, similar to when whistling, while for "chew" the top lip raises up, and the whole mouth area wrinkles up, as if some bad odor had been detected.

Comment: Thiugh this question may be only about English by itself, it might inform some answers if we knew what your native language is (what language you and your teacher communicate in)

Comment: "As a child my English teacher stressed that..." means that when your English teacher was a child, your English teacher suggested something.  I think you mean, "When I was a child, my English teacher stressed that..."

Comment: Just want to point out something about the dangling modifier issue in your sentence, "as a child". It's been suggested that your sentence means something other than what you intended. This isn't the case.  Your sentence is unambiguous when read fully, and its meaning is what people understand it to mean. Just know that some people object to dangling modifiers in many cases, even when there's no ambiguity. Though there's a good case to be made that in your sentence it's not great style.

Comment: If your native language does not have such phonemes, then they will be hard for you to hear and to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the American Heritage Dictionary, Oxford Learner's Dictionary, and as you'll be told by most native English speakers here (I believe), they are pronounced differently:

According to:
American Heritage Dictionary:
two = /to͞o/ [(hear)](http:////img.tfd.com/hm/mp3/T0242200.mp3)
chew = /cho͞o/ [(hear)](http:////img.tfd.com/hm/mp3/C0282000.mp3)
["two" link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/two)
["chew" link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chew)

According to Oxford Learner's Dictionary:
two (BrE) = /tuː/ [(hear)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/media/english/uk_pron/t/two/two__/two__gb_2.mp3)
chew (BrE) = /tʃuː/ [(hear)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/media/english/uk_pron/c/che/chew_/chew__gb_2.mp3)

two (AmE) = /tuː/ [(hear)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/media/english/us_pron/t/two/two__/two__us_1.mp3)
chew (AmE) = /tʃuː/ [(hear)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/media/english/us_pron/c/che/chew_/chew__us_2.mp3)
["two" link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/two?q=two)
["chew" link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chew_1?q=chew)

Whether there are some English accents in which the two words are pronounced the same, I can't say. The fact that your teacher specifically mentioned to distinguish the two sounds suggests to me that where you're from some or many people tend to merge the two pronunciations. To me it sounds like a strange question to ask, but that's likely because I don't know anyone that pronounces those two words the same.